# Capture screenshot with mobile image in Android

Tags: android, screen-capture, android-screen

I have developed an application and need to have the screenshots of the application. I am able to achieve this using the devices/capture screenshot in Eclipse. But, this gives the contents inside the screen. I want the screen shot with the mobile background where i can publish or use it for website. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: try alt+printScreen and paste it somewer( for say word or paint).. i did this for my project..

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, where in devices i need to do this?

Comment: i suppose your using emulator right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Device Art Generator](http://developer.android.com/distribute/promote/device-art.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Some custom ROMs like CyanogenMod have a built-in screen capture 'plug-in' which you can access.

Have you take a look at [this already](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-take-screenshots-on-android/)?